# reading one oracle database writing to another remote oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle10g

c# code: i have 2 oracle databases one is remotely, i am selecting values from my tables in my local oracle database: the query returns 8 columns: i want to write the data in a remote oracle table having different column names and attributes:i want to also make sure that only new row values are inserted:the table structure of my remote database is different from the columns returned by my select query.

my select statement from different table query returns the following: columns: customer_name,customer_id, customer_dep_number,mobile_number, payment_amount, vehicle_model, collection_point, transaction_date

the structure of the remote table is as follows:
TABLE vehicle_bought

BUYER_ID           NUMBER                      NOT NULL,

BUYER_NAME         VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)          NOT NULL,

BUYER_NAT_ID       VARCHAR2(25 BYTE)           DEFAULT 'N/A' NOT NULL,

BUYER_VEHICLE_DESCRIPTION    VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE)         NOT NULL,

BUYER_STATUS       VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)            DEFAULT 'U'
       NOT NULL,

VEHICLE_AMOUNT       NUMBER                      NOT NULL,

CREATED_BY        NUMBER,

TRANS_CREATION_DATE     DATE,

LAST_UPDATED_BY   NUMBER,

LAST_UPDATE_DATE  DATE,

RECEIPT_CREATED   VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)            DEFAULT 'N',

MOBILE_NUM        VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),

VEHICLE_COLLECTION_POINT  VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),

RMA_FLAG          VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)            DEFAULT 'N',

)

the fields i want to read and insert to are as follows:
customer_name = BUYER_NAME,
customer_id = BUYER_ID

customer_dep_number = BUYER_NAT_ID

mobile_number =  MOBILE_NUM

payment_amount = VEHICLE_AMOUNT

vehicle_model = BUYER_VEHICLE_DESCRIPTION

collection_point = VEHICLE_COLLECTION_POINT

transaction_date = TRANS_CREATION_DATE

very urgent language c# please :souvenir promised to whoever helps out.

Comment: BRIBERY! I think there's a standard way of doing that on stackoverflow...

Comment: Not bribery, my culture always teaches us to give a token of appreaciation: kindly assist Sir.Kemp

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution:

1. Create a database link in the remote database (the destination), that connects to the local database (the source)
2. Run the insert across the database link from the remote database, i.e.

   ```
   INSERT INTO desttable (customer_name,
                          customer_id,
                          customer_dep_number,
                          mobile_number, ...)
   SELECT s.buyer_name,
          s.buyer_id,
          s.buyer_nat_id,
          s.mobile_num,
          ...
   FROM   sourcetable@dblink s
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT null FROM desttable
      WHERE desttable.buyer_id = s.buyer_id
   );
   ```

Alternative: a better solution might use a MERGE instead